Are these mathematical symbols $\omega$-limit sets?
Given a system defined by a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with isolated equilibrium solutions, which of the following mathematical symbols could be $\omega$-limit sets for some point?
$$\infty, \circ, \forall, \in$$
This problem really confuses me and I don't understand what should I try… I can only say that $\circ$ could be a closed orbit so that makes sense, but I would like to justify the other options too…
Note: The problem refers to the representation of the $\omega$-limit sets as a graph in $\mathbb{R}^2$: if these could form those symbols.

The $\omega$-limit set is a set.

The problem refers to the representation of the $\omega$-limit sets as a graph in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if these could form those symbols.

Your comment should then be part of the question.

@JohnB Got it! I just edited the question, thanks.

Have you learned about the Poincare-Bendixson theorem? It says that the $\omega$-limit set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can only be a periodic orbit, a fixed point, or a homo/heteroclinic orbit between fixed point(s)

@whpowell96 Yes, although I'm not familiarized with these homo/heteroclinic orbits...

Homoclinic orbits are orbits originating and ending at a single fixed point and heteroclinic orbits connect two fixed points. Each of these symbols can be formed from these by putting a fixed point at each end of a segment and at piont of self-intersection,but it isn't obvious to be whether $\forall$ or $\in$ with their "trailing edges" can be an $\omega$-limit set for a single point.

@whpowell96 So $\infty$ and $\circ$ are, but it is more difficult to see for $\forall$ and $\in$... I understand, thanks! If someone comes up with some examples for $\forall$ or $\in$ then I would appreciate that they could share them if it's okay.
